# Is it possible to view and intercept android's activity launch from a PC

Tags: applications, proxy

I know when a particular activity is launched (for a particular app) it may or may not require additional arguments. Also, if an activity is **exported** then I (or any other app in the device) can launch it manually using adb activity manager like

```
am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

If needed, I can add arguments with this command using **-e** flag as well.

So here is what I expect:

Is there a way which can detect the launch of an android activity and show details such as the package name, name of the activity that is being launched, the arguments which are passed to the activity during launch, etc. I can do this with tools such as [Drozer](https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/tools/drozer/) also

We all know about intercepting proxies such as [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/) which intercepts http requests and show us the headers and body data. I am looking for such a solution. Can this be done?